# Dynamicly set value to reactive form controls Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component with form for creating and updating the user. I get information about user to update through the input parameter `@Input('user') user`. Also I wanna use this parameter to dynamicly paste a data about selected user to the reactive form. I created form like this one:

```
@Input('user') user = new User();      
form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
        id: [{ value: this.user.id, disabled: true }],
        login: [this.user.login],
        password: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
        userName: [this.user.userName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
        email: [this.user.email, [Validators.email]],
        lastLoginDate: [this.user.lastLoginDate],
        loginAttempts: [this.user.loginAttempts],
        passwordChangeDate: [this.user.passwordChangeDate],
        passwordChangeRequired: [this.user.passwordChangeRequired],
        roles: this.fb.array([this.user.roles]),
        isActive: [this.user.isActive]
      });
```

I expected the form control values have to change dynamicly when the `user` is updated. But despite user is updated, values at form are still the same.

[Form photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQR6K.png)

Answer (score 1):

Via the javascript setter method, you can rebuild the form when a new user is set.

```
public user = new User();
@Input('user') set setUser(value){
  this.user = value;
  this.createForm();
}

public form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
  this.createForm();
}

private createForm(){
  this.form = this.fb.group({ ... });
}
```